How to wrap class instances but retain access to attributes as if unwrapped, like pathlib.Path
Is there a way to wrap class instances around each other like below, as many times as needed, while still having access to attributes as if unwrapped?
class MyPath:
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.path = path


print(MyPath('my/file/path.txt').path)
# my/file/path.txt

print(MyPath(MyPath('my/file/path.txt')).path)
# <__main__.MyPath object at 0x105061ed0>

pathlib.Path employs this, but I couldn't figure it out from the source code.
One simplistic possibility is:
class MyPath:
    def __init__(self, instance_or_path=None):
        self._instance_or_path = instance_or_path

    @property
    def path(self):
        if isinstance(self._instance_or_path, MyPath):
            return self._instance_or_path.path
        return self._instance_or_path

But I was thinking there might be a better way, which doesn't require type checking.
Edit: The above solution or the duck typing variation posted by @Andr0id16 is fine if the class only holds a very limited number of attributes, but otherwise seems clunky to me, since the type check or try/except would have to be included for every single one.

pathlib.Path implements os.PathLike and I would expect any related class to do the same. Would that help you?

@Friedrich, perhaps, but I'll have to learn more about abstract base classes to see the relevance. Thanks for pointing me in that direction, though.

you could try something like this, but it depends what your intention would be :
class MyPath:
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self._path = path

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self._path

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self._path}"

print(MyPath("first").path)
print(MyPath(MyPath("second")).path)
print(MyPath(MyPath(MyPath("third"))).path)

>>>first
>>>second
>>>third


You can access the path property recursively and catch the eventual AttributeError when you reach an actual path
@property
    def path(self):
        try:
            return self._instance_or_path.path
        except AttributeError:
            return self._instance_or_path


Thanks! At least this seems to be more pythonic than my initial solution.

You can do it without any explicit conditionals, exception handling or type checking if you allow conversion to str.
For this to work, you need to define a __str__() method.
If it's present, str(MyPath(...)) will either return the path (if it's a string) or recursively call str() on the nested instance.
The recursion ends as soon as you encounter a true str instance.
Also see the Python docs on __str__().
Bottom line: you always get a string.
I added a __str__() method to your sample code:
class MyPath():
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.instance_or_path = path

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.instance_or_path)

    @property
    def path(self):
        return str(self.instance_or_path)


print(MyPath('/tmp/foo').path)
print(MyPath(MyPath('/tmp/nested')).path)
print(MyPath('/tmp/implicit'))
print(MyPath().path)

# Output:
# /tmp/foo
# /tmp/nested
# /tmp/implicit
# None

As can be seen by the line with implicit, we don't even need the path property any more.
Implicit conversion to str is now possible.
In my comment on the question, I mentioned implementing the interface of os.PathLike.
For this, you need to inherit from it and add a __fspath__() method that returns a str or bytes to your class. Luckily, that's not a big change:
import os


class MyPath(os.PathLike):
    # as above
    # ...
    def __fspath__(self):
        return str(self.instance_or_path)
    # or just:
    __fspath__ = __str__


Interesting solution, although I don't quite get the benefit of fspath in this case, since it always returns a string anyway. Can you clarify.

@knerg if you inherit from os.PathLike, you need to have __fspath__(). Otherwise, it will raise an exception. Implementing this interface is a little bit beyond your question. I thought it a good idea to conform to the same interfaces as the built-in classes like pathlib.Path. The benefit is adherence to an established interface - nothing more.
